# Error in Lightning

Tags: lightning, error, rerender, view, aura-if

Since 2 days I'm having this trouble with that error in any views that I don't understand and can't find where it is this error:

> Uncaught rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:if' [Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null]

Comment: Posting the simplest code that demonstrates the problem would help people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. This post solved my problem :
   [Lightning: Bug in Lightning framework when using aura:renderIf?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71604/lightning-bug-in-lightning-framework-when-using-aurarenderif)
   Try using a span around your element inside the aura:if
2. Or you could check this one: [Error "error in 'markup://aura:iteration' : Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null" reported when a component is nested inside aura:iteration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96757/error-error-in-markup-auraiteration-cannot-read-property-childnodes-of). Check the resources that you're including in your component and page
   [if any]. Maybe you're including SLDS twice.

If the above do not work, please post code snippet so we can help.