# salesforce lightning Error: Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

Here is part of my code which fails :

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.layout}" var="item">
        <aura:if istrue="{!(item.elementType == 'HEADER') ? true : false}">
```

I tried rewriting this like this also :

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.layout}" var="item">
        <aura:if istrue="{!item.elementType == 'HEADER'}">
```

But i'm obtaining the same error. Seems like it don't like the item.elementType, where elementType is an attribute of the item instance.

Comment: Did you try this: `<aura:if istrue="{!item.elementType == 'HEADER' ? 'true' : 'false'}">`

Answer (score 2):

Why don´t you add directly a boolean variable to your attribute?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.layout}" var="item">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!item.isHeader}">}
```

Anyway the code your provided should work, I have some similar logic working in my org.

An other comment I want to add is that you should not add an aura:if as an immediate child of aura:iteration, because doing this will cause you unexpected issues due to a [known bug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77730/lightning-component-auraiteration-is-throwing-error-upon-rerendering) in components.

Answer (score 1):

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.layout}" var="item">
         <aura:if istrue="{!item.elementType == 'HEADER' ? 'true' : 'false'}">
```

Hope this would work.

Comment: no it doesn't work. I think that it cannot get access to the elementType attribute , because layout is not defined initially as an array of which type of object. <aura:attribute name="layout"
                    type="list"
                    default="[]"
                    description="The json template in the form of a map to generate the layout" />

Comment: Please provide some description also.