# Issue while removing items from sub components (like from nested component) in Lightning Tree table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a requirement to design a Tree table using lightning components as shown in below image. My tree table has sub components/items which can be removed using Remove button. Here in the example I am displaying Account records as main Items and respective related Contacts as sub items.

[image]

[image]

Now when I remove a Contact clicking on button Remove, then click on Collapse and when I again expand by clicking on the same button I am facing an error displayed in below image.

[image]

Below is the code:

AccountCmp:

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="AccountTestClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:attribute name="icon" type="String" default="plus" />
<aura:attribute name="accountItems" type="Account[]" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#3498db">
            <th></th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountItems}" var="account" indexVar="index">
            <c:removeSubCompCmp account="{!account}" index="{!index}" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
</aura:component>
```

AccountCmpController:

```
({
doInit: function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAccountItems");
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.accountItems", a.getReturnValue());
        } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
            $A.log("Errors", a.getError());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

ContactsCmp:

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" />
<aura:attribute name="icon" type="String" default="plus" />
<aura:attribute name="index" type="integer" />

<tr>
    <td class="slds-size--1-of-12" scope="col">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.icon=='plus'}">
            <ui:button label="Expand" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare" press="{!c.expandSection}" />
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <ui:button label="Collapse" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare" press="{!c.expandSection}" />
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </td>

    <td>{!v.account.Name}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<aura:if isTrue="{!(v.icon == 'minus') &amp;&amp; (v.account.Contacts.length > '0')}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.account.Contacts}" var="contact" indexVar="num">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{!contact.Name}</td>
            <td>
                <ui:button label="Remove" buttonType="{!num}" press="{!c.removeComponent}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

ContactsCmpController:

```
({
expandSection : function(component) {
    if (component.get("v.icon") == "plus") {
        component.set("v.icon", "minus");
    } else {
        component.set("v.icon", "plus");
    }
},

removeComponent: function(component, event) {
    var index = event.getSource().get("v.buttonType");
    var items = component.get("v.account");
    items.Contacts.splice(index, 1);
    component.set("v.account", items);
}
})
```

AccountTestClass:

```
public class AccountTestClass {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> getAccountItems() {

    return [Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) from Account order By Name asc];        

}

}
```

Please try removing components and collapse/expand, we will face the issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two main issues with the solution

1.Splice Javascript function was behaving very weird here.

2.I followed a complete event driven approach to get the Id of the record that you were trying to remove .

Please check the below code which is working as expected in my dev org

The Hierarchy is as follows

AccountList
   ---ContactList
      --------Individual Contact Cards

AccountCmp

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="AccountTestClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

 <aura:attribute name="icon" type="String" default="plus" />
 <aura:attribute name="accountItems" type="Account[]"/>

 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

 <table>
   <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#3498db">
        <th></th>
        <th>Account</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountItems}" var="account" indexVar="index">
           <c:ContactsCmp account="{!account}" contacts="{!account.Contacts}" index="{!index}" />
        </aura:iteration>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</aura:component>
```

The Controller code for client side

```
({
  doInit: function(component) {
  var action = component.get("c.getAccountItems");
  action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.accountItems", a.getReturnValue());
     } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
        $A.log("Errors", a.getError());
      }
    });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   }
 })
```

ContactCmp

```
  <aura:component access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
<aura:attribute name="icon" type="String" default="plus" />
<aura:attribute name="index" type="integer" />


 <aura:handler event="c:contactSync" action="{!c.removeContactFromArray}"/>
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialcall}" />

<tr>
   <td class="slds-size--1-of-12" scope="col">
     <button aura:id="expandPanel" title="Expand" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare" onclick="{!c.expandSection}" >Expand</button>
     <button aura:id="collapsePanel" title="Collapse" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare" onclick="{!c.collapseSection}" >Collapse</button>
   </td>

   <td>{!v.account.Name}</td>
   <td></td>
</tr>

<span aura:id="detailLayout">
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact" indexVar="num">
    <c:ContactCardComponent contactRecord="{!contact}"/>
  </aura:iteration>
</span>

</aura:component>
```

The controller code

```
({
initialcall: function(component) {
    var collapsePanel = component.find("collapsePanel");
    console.log(collapsePanel);
    var detailPanel = component.find("detailLayout");
    $A.util.addClass(collapsePanel,"toggle");
    $A.util.addClass(detailPanel,"toggle");
},

expandSection : function(component) {
    var expandPanel = component.find("expandPanel");
    var collapsePanel = component.find("collapsePanel");
    var detailPanel = component.find("detailLayout");
    $A.util.addClass(expandPanel, "toggle");
    $A.util.removeClass(collapsePanel, "toggle");
    $A.util.removeClass(detailPanel,"toggle");
},

collapseSection : function(component) {
    var expandPanel = component.find("expandPanel");
    var collapsePanel = component.find("collapsePanel");
    var detailPanel = component.find("detailLayout");
    $A.util.removeClass(expandPanel, "toggle");
    $A.util.addClass(collapsePanel, "toggle");
    $A.util.addClass(detailPanel,"toggle");
},

removeContactFromArray : function(component, event) {
   if(event.getParam("accountId") == component.get("v.account").Id){
        var contactId = event.getParam("contactId");
        var contactlist = component.get("v.contacts");
        var ContactRecs = [];
        console.log(contactlist);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < contactlist.length; i++) { 
            console.log(contactlist[i].Id);
            if(contactId == contactlist[i].Id){

            }else{
                ContactRecs.push(contactlist[i]);
            }
        }
        component.set("v.contacts",ContactRecs);
     }
   }
 })
```

The style CSS in the component

```
/*toggleCss.css*/
 .THIS .toggle {
  display: none;
}
 .THIS.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

The Contactcardcomponent

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="contactRecord" type="Contact" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="contactdeleteEvent" type="c:contactSync"/>
     <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{!v.contactRecord.Name}</td>
            <td>
                <ui:button label="Remove" press="{!c.removeComponent}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
 removeComponent: function(component, event) {
    var contactRecord = component.get("v.contactRecord");
    var oldContactId = contactRecord.Id;
    var accountId =  contactRecord.AccountId;
    contactRecord = {};
    component.set("v.contactRecord", contactRecord);
    var deleteContactEvent = $A.get("e.c:contactSync");
   // Optional: set some data for the event (also known as event shape)
     deleteContactEvent.setParams({ "contactId" : oldContactId , "accountId" : accountId});
    deleteContactEvent.fire();
  }
})
```

The event file

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Delete the Contact Id from array">
<aura:attribute name="contactId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String"/>
```

The apex controller code

```
 public class AccountTestClass {

  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Account> getAccountItems() {
    return [Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name ,AccountId from Contacts) from Account order By Name asc];        
   }
 }
```

Also if possible use styling to hide and show and do not use aura:if here.Here is an example of how to do same

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm?search_text=hide

Use class to toggle visibility

Comment: Thank you Mohith, this solution worked for me, why using aura:if we were facing the issue, any inputs ??

Comment: @PradeepChary Look like an issue discussed over [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/77730/20830).Any luck with wrapping the aura:iteration within a span tag.

Comment: Looks like something to do with aura JS I believe .

Comment: @Praveen I always implement in the similar way as mentioned in the link to avoid the "child nodes null" issue. Instead of span I keep 
<tr style="display:none">{!indexVar-variable}</tr>
Here in my above code I am not using span, instead I used table. Like in main component <table> containing only <thead> after this aura:iteration calling child component. In child component <table> having <tbody> . It worked without any UI disturbances.

Comment: The solution from the link didnt work in the scenario I mentioned. What Mohith suggested it worked. @Praveen

Comment: Oh I get it.But I think the issue is something to do with aura as Mohit said.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting an integer into the `buttonType` attribute which is defined as:

> **buttonType**    -> **String**   Specifies the type of button. Possible values: reset, submit, or button. This value defaults to button.

Since `buttonType` is not supposed to hold an integer, lightning is likely enforcing its definition as a string with one of three values. So your index is not being set.

This call will likely result in `undefined` or at least, empty string:

```
var index = event.getSource().get("v.buttonType");
```

Which you then feed into the splice method.

If index is null or empty string, This will definitely cause an error.

In the end, what you should do is try to isolate the error to a very small piece of markup and debug/post that here. It's hard to wade through all the other code to find what is going on with what you have.

Comment: Hi Caspar, thank you for your input, I didnt find any issue using buttonType and javascript splice.