# <aura:iteration> with <aura:if>

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm creating a to do list lightning app.

I iterate over a list of items in my database. Each item has a checkbox field, called `completed__c`. I use an attribute in my lightning component to change if I want the component to display completed, true, or not completed items, false.

I created a lightning event on the newItem form, that adds a new item to the `<c:listItems />`. On the form where the new item is created, it defaults to `completed__c = false`, because why would you create a to do list item that is already completed?

The problem: When the new item is created on the form and is defaulted to `completed__c = true`, the lightning event works and adds it to the `<c:listItems />` component on the page without me manually refreshing. But when I default on the form to `completed__c = false` and set the component attribute to `completed = false`. I get this error

[image]

Here is what my code looks like.

```
<!--c:listItems-->
<aura:attribute name="items" type="item__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="completed" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

<aura:iteration item="{!v.items}" var="item">

    <aura:if isTrue="{!item.completed__c == v.completed}">

        <ui:outputText value="{!item.Name}" />

    <aura:set attribute="else">

    </aura:set>

    </aura:if>

<aura:iteration>

<!--myApp.app-->

<c:listItems completed="false" />
```

Comment: Could it be that <aura:if isTrue="{false == false}"> equals true? So if the whole statement is true in that instance, and will only let true items to be put in that component. Since I'm creating an item is completed == false, the event won't push.

Comment: Hi Tyler, Are you using the Chrome Plugin for Lightning and if so, when you look at the value for items, what is it showing? Also, is this code for a child component and if so, you might want to show the code for the parent component that calls this component. It might show something.

Comment: Interesting, using the Chrome Plugin, items = "[]", and when I click on the [], the array is holding both completed__c (true) and not completed__c(false), items.

This is not a child component. The component is right in the app file.

Comment: What happens if you change the conditional to this: !item.completed__c === v.completed with a different equality check?

Comment: I get this error "Failed to save undefined: expecting '=', found ' ' at column 47 of expression: item.completed__c === v.completed: Source"

Comment: Let me think about this some more. I am at work now and can't really get to it until this weekend. Let me know if you figure it out in the meantime.

Comment: I guess I could create two attributes <aura:attribute name="completedItems" type="item__c[]"/> & <aura:attribute name="notCompleteitems" type="item__c[]"/>, use each attribute in a different <aura:iteration>, then use an <aura:if> to choose which iteration to execute based on the value of my completed attribute. That seems a bit messy though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at all the code you sent me, I am pretty sure the problem you are encountering is the same as the one [reported here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71604/lightning-bug-in-lightning-framework-when-using-aurarenderif), which appears to be a Framework issue yet to be resolved.

That said, I have a better workaround than the one one suggested in that post. The problem seems to happen when the call returns an empty array such as what would happen for those items marked non-completed. But, it occurred to me that you might want to re-consider how you are getting the data and instead of returning all the data in each doInit and then using the aura:if to only display what you want. Instead you can resolve this (and I verified it worked by the way), by simply changing your code to pass the completed flag to the getWhiteboardItemsDB method in your Apex class and only return the data you actually want.

This would involve changing the code in your Apex Controller to look like the following:

```
public with sharing class ListWhiteboardItemsApexController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Whiteboard_Item__c> getWhiteboardItemsDB(Boolean completed) {
    return [SELECT Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, 
            AssignedTo__c, Completed__c, CompletedBy__c, Completed_Date__c, High_Priority__c, Display__c, Item_Due_Date__c
            FROM Whiteboard_Item__c
           WHERE Completed__c =: completed];
}
 }
```

And also change the code in the helper function that calls this method to look like the following:

```
 getWhiteboardItems : function(component) {
    var action = component.get('c.getWhiteboardItemsDB');
    var completed = component.get('v.completed');
    action.setParams({ "completed" : completed});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.whiteboardItems", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

You can then leave your code in the ListItems component with the aura:if and it should work without getting the error.

Please let me know if you think this would work and if so, mark this as the answer so it can possibly help other people.

Answer (score 1):

remove the *aura:set* tag from our code, empty aura:set tags cause errors, that is make your code :

```
<!--c:listItems-->
<aura:attribute name="completed" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">

    <aura:if isTrue="{!item.completed__c == v.completed}">

        <ui:outputText value="{!item.Name}" />

   </aura:if>
<aura:iteration>
```

Comment: that didn't work. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: can you try making the 'item' attribute to 'items' that's a typo, I'm editing my answer also

Comment: Also the aura:if tag is not closed properly in the code snippet posted as a part of the question

Comment: Good eye. Fixed that on my post. The if was there in my actual code.

Comment: did that work for you Tyler ?

Comment: No it did not :(