# Rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:if' [Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null] Failing descriptor: {markup://aura:if}

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

My If-Iteration structure is similar to written below

```
<aura:if isTrue="">
<ul>
  <aura:if isTrue="">
  </aura:if>

  <aura:if isTrue="">
  </aura:if>

  <aura:iteration>
   <li>
   </li>
  </aura:iteration>
</ul>
</aura:if>
```

Everything goes smoothly but when the above div is rerendered then the below-mentioned error comes

rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:if'

> [Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null] Failing descriptor:
>   {markup://aura:if}

I also tried to wrap  in  but it does not work. (which was given in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71604/lightning-bug-in-lightning-framework-when-using-aurarenderif))

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am still stuck also and have read all similar posts!

Comment: @dacology, nope.

Comment: I'm also stuck with this arbitrary error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should also try to seperate the `aura:if` from the `aura:iteration` using the same technique.

Try something like this:

```
<aura:if isTrue="">
  <ul>
    <span>
      <aura:if isTrue="">
      </aura:if>
    </span

    <span>
      <aura:if isTrue="">
      </aura:if>
    </span

    <span>
      <aura:iteration>
       <li>
       </li>
      </aura:iteration>
    </span>
  </ul>
</aura:if>
```

If this does not work, try to determine which `aura:if` is causing the problem - try to remove the outer and inner `aura:if` and the `aura:iteration` statements separately to see if you can alter the rendering behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like this

```
<aura:if isTrue="">
<ul>
<aura:if isTrue="">
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="">
</aura:if>

<aura:iteration>
<span>
  <li>
  </li>
</span>
</aura:iteration>
</ul>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: Why would adding a span around the `<li>` elements make any difference?